# FileNotFoundException with image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, filenotfoundexception

so, I have this problem and it's very strange.
I've to show an image in a print preview and I added it in the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

[image]

When I'm debugging or I'm using the application opened from the .exe, I'm given the following exception

FileNotFoundException

in this row

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("image.JPG"), nWidth - 150, nHeight, 150, 20)
```

image.JPG is the one added in the Solution Explorer.
The path is

C:\Users\loretta\Desktop\Billie Jean 19\MyProject\WindowsApplication1\image.JPG

I changed the istruction above with this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\loretta\Desktop\Billie Jean 19\FraMe Errors\WindowsApplication1\image.JPG"), nWidth - 150, nHeight, 150, 20)
```

and it works...
Why don't I get the expection? I wonder if the first way is correct and if there are mistakes, I'd like to have the proper solution without writing the path.

Thanks in advance to everyone...

Comment: Embedded resources! It's looks from the file path "image.jpg" which doesn't exist on your desktop/memory! The from file looks at image.jpg to see whats there. Try embedding it into your application or form. like a background image in a picture box.

Comment: if it is a static image (one you want the app to be able to use) just add it to Resources and load it from there.  Adding a copy to the solution folders doesnt do what you think it does.

Comment: I really don't understand why some people always downvotes questions that are written and are asked so right like this...

Comment: Set the `Copy to output folder` property of the image (in Visual Studio) to any value but `never` (which is default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either ElektroStudios solution or using My.Resources.

**My.Resources:**

Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and press "Properties".

Then go to the "Resources" tab, and switch from Strings to Images (if not selected already). ['Strings' does not have to be the first selected option]

Then either press "Add resource" or drag and drop images inside it. The images can then be accessed my using "My.Resources.(image name)"

Read this article for further info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of your built application is `...\Bin\Debug` and `...\Bin\Release` respectivelly (see: [StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so if you want to use local images instead resources you need to put the image in the proper working directory, not in the solution directory.